PWA does not reinstall
It appears that once a PWA is installed, and then deleted, it can not be installed again.

On Android, clicking on Save to Home Screen shows an option to Install.
If this PWA is deleted from the home screen.
Clicking on Save to Home Screen no longer shows an option to Install.

I have tested this on Android S20 and S24. And also on iPhone 11.

I have restarted the phone.
The PWA does not appear in Settings-> Apps, so nothing can be deleted.

Is there a way to get around this?

Should we know what PWA is?
